# Glass becomes non-responsive when debugging

Tags: google-glass

I get the following exception and the glass becomes nonresponse. The light LED is solid and the glass requires a Hard Reset. Its becoming quite frequently when debugging android apps.

```
com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Read-only file system
```

What does the error mean in context to glass and how to prevent from occurring

Tools used: ADT eclipse when running or debugging a project.

the stack trace looks like

```
[2014-02-12 15:42:08 - MainActivity] Uploading MainActivity.apk onto device '015DB76E1401D00C'
[2014-02-12 15:42:08 - MainActivity] Failed to install MainActivity.apk on device '015DB76E1401D00C': Read-only file system
[2014-02-12 15:42:08 - MainActivity] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Read-only file system
[2014-02-12 15:42:08 - MainActivity] Launch canceled!
[2014-02-12 15:45:41 - MainActivity] ------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you check how much free space there is on your Glass?

Comment: over 10gb. storage is definitely not an issue.

Comment: Is this stock Glass Explorer edition, or did you root it, or do other 'weird' stuff? Any problems just launching a new app but not in debug mode in Eclipse?

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate this issue again